# Windows identity foundation claims access from wcf service

Tags: wcf, wif, claims

when I try to get the Claims from the WCF method implementation, I get an object of type `System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal` and it should be an object of type `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal`. Does anybody know what am I missing in the settings to achieve this object?

Line of code : IClaimsPrincipal principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as IClaimsPrincipal;

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the code you are running to get the claims??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to configure the claims-aware service to use WIF by writting  `FederatedServiceCredentials.ConfigureServiceHost` at the service factory